# Is there any method that can get facebook user info when the user click on share button

Tags: facebook

I have plugin the facebook sharer into my website.

The thing I want to do is when user share the page, I need to backup the user info in my database.

Please share me if there is any method or api can get these info.

Comment: Why would you need to backup the user info in your database? No that is not possible

Comment: you can only get user data if the user specifically authorizes your app, and even then you need to tell him exactly what you want to store, with a proper privacy policy and stuff.